# Dynamic template rendering in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I found a link regarding dynamically loading of template in Angular 2 component here http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3101-experimenting-with-dynamic-template-rendering-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm.

I am trying to implement this in beta.9 which makes the plunker to break http://plnkr.co/edit/g9Mect63GoaybJmqLMef?p=preview. What are the breaking changes in angular2 rc-1 which makes my plunker not work?

Here is his plunker demo in rc-1 http://plnkr.co/edit/6cwYyfPUJZYOMM5YD1IB?p=preview. I can't spot the error since there are no errors also showing in Console window.

```
        <dynamic-repeater [items]="colors">
        <template #itemRenderer #color="item" #index="index">
            <div title="Item {{ index }}" class="swatch" [style.backgroundColor]="color.hex">
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                {{ color.name }}
            </div>
        </template>
    </dynamic-repeater>
```

Comment: And you want to make it work in beta.9 or in RC.1?

Comment: I want it to work in beta.9

Comment: What's the problem? I don't see an error in any of these two Plunkers. Uh, I guess you want the same behavior. Got it.

Comment: In the second plunker you will see the data which is passed as input,i mean i am able to see the div with appropriate color which is passed into the child component but in the first plunker i am not able to see any output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 contains Plunker in a few versions. I don't know if `ViewContainerRef.createXxx` was available this way in beta.15 or even beta.9.

Comment: Thanks...viewContainerRef was added as a breaking change in Beta.16... But brother i have a question regarding this dynamic template rendering.How is dynamic template rendering helpful? I mean in the plunker(rc-1 example) i have passed data into the child component and also the format to apply ngFor...What advantage do i have by doing like this... In what situations this kind of approach would be helpful...Any suggestion will be helpful for me brother

Comment: When the component you want to add is not known statically. If you can add `<my-comp></my-comp>` to the template, then there is no need for `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`. I didn't have a very close look at your Plunker but it looks like it is used to create components at runtimer (maybe for user-provided HTML). There is currently no other way to support binding with user-provided HTML.

Comment: Ok...Thank you brother

Comment: ... and if you just want to allow the user of your component to pass a component to be used in your component (other that just transclution).